# System.IO relative path

Tags: c#, path, .net

I am trying to read a file from my solution.  I want to know how to locate the file using a relative path.  My solution contains *3 projects*.  The file I want to read is located in *project A*, but the code that is reading it is located in *project B*.  If I use `..\file.txt` that will bring me to *Project B* rather than *Project A*.  If I use `Application.StartPath`
I get

*`C:\\Users\\Linda\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\10.0\\Extensions\\tangible\\t4 editor\\2.1.1`*

whereas I need to find the directory where I have developed the code `C:\Sp_CodeGenerator\...`

I have also tried using

```
Environment.GetFolderPath

Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath))'`
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
```

but these all produce the same results and bring me to Visual Studio Program files rather than to where the solution has been created on the hard disk.

Anything else I should try?

Comment: What would you expect the location "where the solution has been created on the hard disk" to be when executed on a system that does not have the source code present?

Comment: Have you tried setting a working directory in the project properties?

Comment: Perhaps you should set the file properties to "copy file to output directory"  and then just look for it in the same directory as the executing assembly (something like `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`).

Comment: Dtb I'm not sure how to set a working directory in project properties or if I understand what you mean? I see an option to create reference paths under the project properties tab - is this what you are alluding to?

Comment: phoog I had considered that, and if I can't find a better solution I'll probably run with that.  Thanks

Comment: cdhowie - It's a code generation tool that works as an Extension for Entity Frameworks so I'm trying to reference a file that is created by Entity Frameworks

Comment: Does the tool have access to Visual Studio [Macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) variables? If so, you can use `$(SolutionDir)`.

Comment: Afraid not - that seems to look in the same directory again.         Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Linda\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions\tangible\t4 editor\2.1.1\$(SolutionDir)\Templates\XMLFiles\AndOrOpertor.xml'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're executing the path related code from within a t4 template?  This actually will affect the answer since all the normal means of dealing with paths will be in the context of visual studio and the t4 editor plugin you're using.

You need to access the ITextTemplatingEngineHost to properly resolve your paths.

Add a hostspecific director to your template

```
<#@template language="c#" hostspecific="true" #>
```

Then you can access it via

```
this.Host.ResolvePath(path);

//also available (Gets the path and file name of the text template that is being processed.)
//this.Host.TemplateFile
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.itexttemplatingenginehost(v=vs.110).aspx